# Start PyGTK cellrenderer edit from code

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk, gnome

I have a treeview with an editable CellRendererText:

```
self.renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
self.renderer.set_property('editable', True)
```

But now I need to launch the edition from code instead from user, this is to focus the user attention in the fact he just created a new row and needs to be named. I tried this but does not work:

```
self.renderer.start_editing(
    gtk.gdk.Event(gtk.gdk.NOTHING),
    self.treeview,
    str(index),
    gtk.gdk.Rectangle(),
    gtk.gdk.Rectangle(),
    0)
```

Neither does not throw errors, but the documentation about for what is each argument is not clear, in fact I really don't know if start_editing method is for this.

All suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> def set_cursor(path, focus_column=None, start_editing=False)
> ```
>
> ... If *column* is specified, and *start_editing* is True, then editing should be started in the specified cell. This method is often followed by the `gtk.Widget.grab_focus()` method to give keyboard focus to the treeview.

[Source](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--set-cursor)

Comment: This works like a charm, in addition start_editing does not need to be enabled. Thanks a lot.