# How to activate a cell in tree view for editing

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I have a simple tree view with text-based cells. I would like to be able to open the currently selected cell for editing by pressing the F2 key. In other words, the F2 key should behave exactly the same way as the Enter key does now, when a cell is selected. (It opens a little box in which I can edit the contents of the cell.)

I could not figure out what to call in order to activate that little box.

I include a minimum working example:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> ApplicationRef;
typedef Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore>   ListStoreRef;

using namespace std;

class Example : public Gtk::Window
{

public:
    Example()
    {
        m_list_store_ref = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_model_columns);
        m_tree_view.set_model(m_list_store_ref);

        // Fill in the model with dummy data.
        m_add_row("apple", "lettuce");
        m_add_row("orange", "broccoli");
        m_add_row("banana", "cauliflower");

        // Add columns to the tree view.
        m_tree_view.append_column_editable("Fruit", m_model_columns.m_fruit);
        m_tree_view.append_column_editable("Vegetables", m_model_columns.m_vegetables);

        add(m_tree_view);

        add_events(Gdk::KEY_PRESS_MASK);

        show_all_children();
    }
    virtual ~Example() {}

protected:
    //Signal handlers:
    void on_button_clicked() { hide(); }

    //Member widgets:
    Gtk::TreeView m_tree_view;

    // Other objects
    ListStoreRef m_list_store_ref;

    // Model columns
    class ModelColumns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord
    {
    public:
        ModelColumns() { add(m_fruit); add(m_vegetables); }

        Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> m_fruit;
        Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> m_vegetables;
    };

    ModelColumns m_model_columns;

    void m_add_row(Glib::ustring fruit, Glib::ustring vegetable)
    {
        auto row = *(m_list_store_ref->append());
        row[m_model_columns.m_fruit]      = fruit;
        row[m_model_columns.m_vegetables] = vegetable;
    }


    bool on_key_press_event(GdkEventKey* event)
    {
        if (event->keyval==GDK_KEY_F2) {
            cout << "F2 was pressed." << endl;

            // What code should go here to make the currently selected cell active for editing?

            return true;
        }

        return Gtk::Window::on_key_press_event(event);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ApplicationRef app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.mwe");
    Example example;
    return app->run(example);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. (The key was the post entitled [Start PyGTK cellrenderer edit from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576481/start-pygtk-cellrenderer-edit-from-code).) Here is the same MWE, which has the behavior I want:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> ApplicationRef;
typedef Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore>   ListStoreRef;

using namespace std;

class Example : public Gtk::Window
{

public:
    Example()
    {
        m_list_store_ref = Gtk::ListStore::create(m_model_columns);
        m_tree_view.set_model(m_list_store_ref);

        // Fill in the model with dummy data.
        m_add_row("apple", "lettuce");
        m_add_row("orange", "broccoli");
        m_add_row("banana", "cauliflower");

        // Add columns to the tree view.
        m_tree_view.append_column_editable("Fruit", m_model_columns.m_fruit);
        m_tree_view.append_column_editable("Vegetables", m_model_columns.m_vegetables);

        add(m_tree_view);

        add_events(Gdk::KEY_PRESS_MASK);

        show_all_children();
    }
    virtual ~Example() {}

protected:
    //Signal handlers:
    void on_button_clicked() { hide(); }

    //Member widgets:
    Gtk::TreeView m_tree_view;

    // Other objects
    ListStoreRef m_list_store_ref;

    // Model columns
    class ModelColumns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord
    {
    public:
        ModelColumns() { add(m_fruit); add(m_vegetables); }

        Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> m_fruit;
        Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> m_vegetables;
    };

    ModelColumns m_model_columns;

    void m_add_row(Glib::ustring fruit, Glib::ustring vegetable)
    {
        auto row = *(m_list_store_ref->append());
        row[m_model_columns.m_fruit]      = fruit;
        row[m_model_columns.m_vegetables] = vegetable;
    }


    bool on_key_press_event(GdkEventKey* event)
    {
        if (event->keyval==GDK_KEY_F2) {
            cout << "F2 was pressed." << endl;

            Gtk::TreeModel::Path path;
            Gtk::TreeViewColumn* col;

            m_tree_view.get_cursor(path, col);
            auto cell = col->get_first_cell();

            // If the cell is being edited, cancel the editing;
            // if the cell is not being edited, start editing.
            if(cell->property_editing()) {
                m_tree_view.set_cursor(path, *col, false);
            } else {
                m_tree_view.set_cursor(path, *col, true);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return Gtk::Window::on_key_press_event(event);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ApplicationRef app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.mwe");
    Example example;
    return app->run(example);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle editable / non-editable with F2 key by below code.

```
bool on_key_press_event(GdkEventKey* event)
{
    if (GDK_KEY_F2) {
        cout << "F2 was pressed." << endl;

        // What code should go here to make the currently selected cell active for editing?
        Gtk::CellRendererText *column_fruit = (Gtk::CellRendererText*)m_tree_view.get_column_cell_renderer(0);
        Gtk::CellRendererText *column_vegetable = (Gtk::CellRendererText*)m_tree_view.get_column_cell_renderer(1);
        column_fruit->property_editable() = !column_fruit->property_editable();
        column_vegetable->property_editable() = !column_vegetable->property_editable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I needed. I don't need it to be *editable*, but in the active editing state (as if I pressed Enter).

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't have the brief idea. To get the focus column is difficult, Calcurating a cordinate of pointer needed.

Comment: Another resource for this is https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Tree_View/Editable_Cells.